# Horizontal version of Print[]

Tags: printing, mathematica-online

With the following code I produce the binary digits of n=13:

```
n=13;

Q = Quotient[n, 2]; 

While[Q != 0, Print[Mod[n, 2]]; Q = Quotient[n, 2]; n = Q]
```

The problem is that it outputs the digits as

```
1

0

1

1
```

but I want them to appear horizontally `1101`. What is the most direct way to produce the desired effect regarding the output's style?

Comment: [`IntegerString[13, 2]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerString.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated to reverse the result of OP's loop

This makes a list (which needs to be reversed):

```
Q = Quotient[n, 2];
result = {};
While[Q != 0, AppendTo[result, Mod[n, 2]]; Q = Quotient[n, 2]; n = Q]

Reverse[result]
```

> {1, 1, 0, 1}

If you want a string:

```
StringJoin[ToString /@ Reverse[result]]
```

> "1101"

There's also

```
BaseForm[13, 2]
```

[image]

```
IntegerString[13, 2]
```

> "1101"

Answer (score 3):

> What is the most direct way to produce the desired effect?

Do not use Print. I am sure there are at least 10 ways to do this, one way could be to replace `Print` by `Sow` and keeping your main logic as is. But this can also be done with explicit loop

```
doit[n_Integer?Positive]:=Module[{m=n,q},
   q=Quotient[m,2];
   While[q!=0,
     Sow[Mod[m,2]];
     q=Quotient[m,2];
     m=q
  ]
]
```

And now do

```
r = First@Last@Reap@doit[13];
StringJoin[ToString /@ Reverse[r]]
ToExpression[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
BaseForm[13,2]
```

or more generally

```
BaseForm[n,base]
```

Answer (score 2):

"What is the most direct way to produce the desired effect?"

```
BaseForm[13, 2]
```