# How can I convert an integer to a binary list?

Tags: list-manipulation, number-bases

Given a integer n, e.g. n = 6, convert this to a binary list, ln = {1,1,0}.

Comment: See the answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290574/horizontal-version-of-print)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Horizontal version of Print\[\]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290574/horizontal-version-of-print)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`IntegerDigits`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerDigits.html):

```
IntegerDigits[6, 2]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 0}
> ```